# change value of a cookie

Tags: cookies, asp-classic, vbscript

I create a simple page , that checked Username and Password with HTML forms, I want to know , how many times someone logged in With this username and password:

Username:Admin
Password:Admin

I think I have to use Cookies or Sessions , but I can't change these values and I can't Add 1 to these every time someone logged in.

what can I do for solve this Problem?
(I'm beginner on asp classic.)

Comment: why you want to use cookie this can be done at server side?

Comment: this is a homework assignment

Comment: this is my question, what is the difference if it was for my homework or my self or my project, i just want to know how to change the value of a cookie!!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's totally possible to do that with cookies.
For a brief introduction to cookies, you can take a look at [this](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_cookies.asp) page. 
Yea, yea, w3schools, I know.

Excerpt:

```
' to set a value of a cookie
Response.Cookies("firstname")="Alex"

' to retrieve a value of an existing cookie:
dim fname : fname = Request.Cookies("firstname")
```

As other people have noted, in a real-world scenario you might want to use a database for storing data. In that case, cookies will only contain the unique identifier of the user.

Answer (score 0):

This information should be stored in the user table in the database.

Sessions/cookies are stored on the user's machine and they'll expire and the data will be lost. You need to keep this information on the server with other information about your users.

Comment: I know that, but the point is , the teacher want this without Database , and it is just for one user

Comment: this is my question, what is the difference if it was for my homework or my self or my project, i just want to know how to change the value of a cookie!!! your vote is so unfair